# MySQL: Change value from '0' to '1' in a table - ONLY CERTAIN ROWS

Tags: mysql, rows

I try to change the value from '0' to '1' of a column in my table. But I need the change only between row 1 and 100.

This is the status quo.

```
+-------+--------+
|  pid  |  value | 
|  1    |    0   |
|  2    |    0   |
|  ..   |    0   |
|  100  |    0   |
|  101  |    0   |
```

The table should be:

```
+-------+--------+
|  pid  |  value | 
|  1    |    1   |
|  2    |    1   |
|  ..   |    1   |
|  100  |    1   |
|  101  |    0   |
```

I tried this: `SELECT * FROM vxg_posts WHERE pid BETWEEN 1 AND 10088`

In the column "validated" I try to set the value to 1. But only between 1 and 10088

Comment: Please show us some data, along with table structure.  Your question cannot be answered in its current form.

Comment: I tried this:
SELECT *  FROM `vxg_posts` WHERE `pid` BETWEEN 1 AND 10088

In the column "validated" I try to set the value to 1. But only between 1 and 10088.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, I found this link already, but I don't understand how it should work.

Comment: Please show us some data, along with table structure. Your question cannot be answered in its current form.

Comment: I edited my question. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: You can use the WHERE clause in an UPDATE statement.

Comment: Sorry @PaulSpiegel, I'm a real newbie in MySQL, can you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the WHERE clause in an UPDATE statement. The syntax is documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html).

In your case it would be something like:

```
UPDATE vxg_posts
SET value = 1
WHERE pid BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

It's also possible to use the LIMIT clause:

```
UPDATE vxg_posts
SET value = 1
ORDER BY pid ASC
LIMIT 100
```

If the values in `pid` column are consecutive, the two statements will do the same.